# How to test for the presence of a year, but without surrounding brackets, in a foldernames using Python

Tags: python-3.x

My Movie collection is stored in folders like this:

```
D:\Movies\Batman (2000)\Batman.mp4
D:\Movies\Superman (2001)\Superman.mp4
D:\Movies\Wonder Woman 2002\Wonder Woman.mp4
```

Most of my movies have the year in the foldername, surrounded by smooth brackets i.e. "(" and ")".

However some of my movies have the year in foldername but without the brackets, see e.g. the Wonder Woman 2002 folder.

I know how to use os.walk to walk over all the foldernames.

How can I scan for the presence of folders that contain a year where that year does not have brackets, and then rename the folder to include the brackets?

Comment: What can we assume? For example, can we assume that all folders in the directory which have a number somewhere in the name are movie folders?

Answer (score 0):

### Here you go:

```py
import os

file_list = os.listdir()
for each in file_list:
    if not "(" in each:
        # Finds the index of the last space in 
        last_space_idx = each.rfind(" ")

        # Also check if there is a space somewhere in the file.
        # If so, rename it to the below format.
        if last_space_idx != -1:
            os.rename(each, "%s (%s)" % (each[:last_space_idx], each[last_space_idx + 1:]))
```

It's a very simple checker that just confirms if there is a `(` anywhere in the name of the folder. I didn't want to put too many conditionals since it will decrease the speed of the program, but more conditionals can be easily added. Also it seems like the folder only has movie names, so there should be little to no edge cases for you. Let me know if you have any questions or would like more restrictions added.

Comment: Python says FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Timeline 2003' -> 'Timeline (2003)'

on line

    os.rename(each, "%s (%s)" %
                      (each[:last_space_idx], each[last_space_idx + 1:]))

Comment: Is the python file in the same folder as all the movie folders? "D:\Movies\" in your case, I believe.